# Python command only work in direct messages?

Tags: discord.py

So I want to be able to have my command only work in direct messages, can anyone help?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('bb!help'):
        await message.channel.send('Huge long commands list')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isinstance()`.

`isinstance` checks whether if an object has the specified type. For example, `isinstance(3, int)` checks if 3 is an integer (which it is and therefore returns `True`). In your case you could check if the `message.channel` is a `DMChannel`. The correct code would be:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('bb!help') and isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        await message.channel.send('Huge long commands list')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `commands.Bot`

```py
@client.command()
@commands.dm_only()
async def command(ctx):
   ...
```

If you're using `on_message`

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        # The message is sent in the dm's of the bot
```